# cual es mi error en el codigo?

Tags: javascript

```js
function buscandoAWally(array) {
  // La función llamada 'buscandoAWally' recibe como argumento un arreglo de 'string' y debe devolver un 'string' que diga
  // 'Encontre a Wally en la posicion [indice del arreglo donde esta]'
  // Ej:
  // buscandoAWally(['Dobby', 'Harry', 'Dementor', 'Wally', 'Sirius']) debe retornar 'Encontre a Wally en la posicion 3'
  // ya que 'Wally' se encuentra en la posicion 3 del arreglo.
  // Tu código aca:

var string = array.filter(Wally => array.indexOf(Wally));
return "Encontre a Wally en la posicion" + string; 

}
```

Comment: Debe ser: `var posicion = array.indexOf("Wally")`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el método `indexOf` de JavaScript para buscar el índice de un elemento en un array.

```
function buscandoAWally(array) {
    return "Encontré a Wally en la posición " + array.indexOf("Wally") + " del arreglo."; 
}
```